# Can the optidef package accommodate breaking a long constraint?

Tags: math-mode, package-options

The [optidef package](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/optidef/optidef.pdf) accommodates breaking a long objective function using the `\breakObjective` command (documentation section 9.9). I have a *constraint* that is too long. The workaround below uses `\breakObjective` for the constraint and does the job, but is there a better way?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{optidef}

\begin{document}

The constraint below is too long:

\begin{maxi}
    { \{C_s\}_{s = t}^\infty }{ \sum_{s = t}^\infty \beta^{s-t} u(C_s) }{}{}
    \addConstraint{ C_s + a + b + c + d + e + f + g }{ =  h + i + j + k + l + m + n + o + p. }{}
\end{maxi}

Using the breakObjective command helps:

\begin{maxi}
    { \{C_s\}_{s = t}^\infty }{ \sum_{s = t}^\infty \beta^{s-t} u(C_s) }{}{}
    \addConstraint{ C_s + a + b + c + d + e + f + g }
    \breakObjective{= h + i + j + k + l + m + n + o + p. }
\end{maxi}

Adding qquad indents to the second line, conforming AMS style:

\begin{maxi}
    { \{C_s\}_{s = t}^\infty }{ \sum_{s = t}^\infty \beta^{s-t} u(C_s) }{}{}
    \addConstraint{ C_s + a + b + c + d + e + f + g }
    \breakObjective{ \qquad = h + i + j + k + l + m + n + o + p. }
\end{maxi}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I am running into the same problem now. Please write answer if you solved it.

Comment: I think I dropped optidef in favor of manual typesetting. It’s slower, but you have much more control...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found a simple solution:
Open a new constraint and leave the first bracket empty:

```
\begin{maxi}
{ \{C_s\}_{s = t}^\infty }{ \sum_{s = t}^\infty \beta^{s-t} u(C_s) }{}{}
\addConstraint{C_s + a + b + c + d + e + f + g = }{}
\addConstraint{}{  h + i + j + k + l + m + n + o + p. }
\end{maxi}
```

Works even better than \breakObjective, since it does not add a new *s.t.*